# Plotting Absolute value =1 of a complex function

Tags: plotting

I would like to report a possible bug in Mathematica, either Cloud or 12.2.

If one plots:

```
u0[r_, phi_] := Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -5, 5}];
{Plot3D[Re[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> True , 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> 12, ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 Plot3D[Im[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> True , 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> 12,  ColorFunction -> Hue]}
```

It gives

[image: Plots]

However, if one wishes to plot |u0|=1 it gives a flat landscape:

```
{Plot3D[Abs[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> True , 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> 12, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[Arg[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> True , 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> 12, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Flat]

Then if one wishes to correct and go back to plot the original form:

```
u0[r_, phi_] := Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -5, 5}];
{Plot3D[Re[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> True , 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> 12, ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 Plot3D[Im[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> True , 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> 12,  ColorFunction -> Hue]}
```

then that becomes flat too!

What is wrong here?

Comment: In "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" the first plot looks like yours, the Abs plot is not flat and the third looks exactly like the first

Comment: Use a direct assigment `u0[r_, phi_] = Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -5, 5}]` without terminating semicolon, and check if the definition is actually correct. Also, `?u0` will tell you if the definition was successful.

Comment: `u0[r_, phi_] := Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -5, 5}]; Map[Plot3D[#[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> 12, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLabel -> Style[#, 14, Bold], PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> 288]&, {{Re, Im}, {Abs, Arg}}, {2}] // Grid`

Comment: Thanks. However, we want to make sure that  the magnitude of the plane wave expansion Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi] is equal to one, therefore the code should be as given  (namely Absu0=1). How do  you get this not-flat @Andreas ?

Comment: to get a normalized plot you have to take u/Abs[u] like in the answer by bob below

Comment: Thank you very much, all!

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

u0[r_, phi_] := Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -5, 5}]

Map[Plot3D[#[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi},
    PlotRange -> All,
    AxesLabel -> Automatic,
    AxesStyle -> 12,
    ColorFunction -> Hue,
    PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["``@u0", #], 14, Bold],
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    ImageSize -> 288,
    PlotRange -> All] &,
  {{Re, Im}, {Abs, Arg}}, {2}] //
 Grid
```

[image]

The normalization of `u0` would **define a new function**, call it `u0n`

```
u0n[r_, phi_] := u0[r, phi]/Abs[u0[r, phi]]

Map[Plot3D[#[u0n[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi},
    PlotRange -> All,
    AxesLabel -> Automatic,
    AxesStyle -> 12,
    ColorFunction -> Hue,
    PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["``@u0n", #], 14, Bold],
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    ImageSize -> 288,
    PlotRange -> All] &,
  {{Re, Im}, {Abs, Arg}}, {2}] //
 Grid
```

[image]

A numeric example

```
#[2., 1.] & /@ {u0, u0n}

(* {0.47311 - 0.882511 I, 0.472482 - 0.88134 I} *)

Abs[%]

(* {1.00133, 1.} *)
```